# Using JQuery 1.10.2 and mootools-1.3.2 in the same document

Tags: jquery, mootools

I'm currently in the process of skinning our application using a html template provided to us by our client. Unfortunately, they have some elements in their template that require the use of mootools. I am not familiar with this library and prefer to use jQuery. Is there any way of allowing the use of a few jQuery scripts without breaking the underlying mootools that has already been programmed?

I have tried the following rather than using $:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".jobpost_body .jobclass .jobvalue").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).html(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).html()));
});
```

});

However, it still appears to break the mootools elements. In particular, Firebug gives the following error:

```
TypeError: $(...).getCoordinates is not a function
coordinates = $('site_icons_info').getCoordinates();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have never dealt with mootools before.

Comment: did you do `jQuery.noConflict()`? mootools will assume `document.id` if `$` is not free.

Comment: Include jQuery first, then mootools. Otherwise, you must use jQuery.noConflict().

Comment: I tried including jQuery first and then mootools. This is not a viable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sort of fixed this myself. The following appears to provide the desired results:

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".jobpost_body .jobclass .jobvalue").each(function(){
                    jQuery(this).html(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).html()));
    });
 });
```

Comment: To make your code cleaner, you can do this: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ $(".jobpost_body .jobclass .jobvalue").etc...` assuming you don't need to use mootools inside your jQuery doc ready handler. Now, as long as you are inside the dom ready handler, you can safely use `$` to reference `jQuery`

Comment: sorry, pressed enter by habit.